# Bootstrapping more efficiently than a nested for loop

Tags: r

I have written the following for loop too bootstrap across a number of cameras put out across a long period of time to capture different species. I want to run it, say, 100 times for each combination of n_cameras and days.

I know this isn't the most efficient way to do this - i there  a way I could do the same in tidyverse? O at least use it to take out the nested loops.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)
library(terra)

Sites<-c("Site1","Site2","Site3","Site4","Site5","Site6")
Dates<-seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-15"), by="days")
Species<-c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3")

lonlat<-data.frame(
  lon = c(15.0, 25.0, 12.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0),
  lat = c(22.0, 18.0, 25.0, 20.0, 18.0, 25.0),
  SiteID=Sites
)


df<-data.frame(
  SiteID=sample(Sites,20, replace=TRUE),
  Date=sample(Dates,20, replace=TRUE),
  Species=sample(Species,20, replace=TRUE),
  Count=sample(0:3,20, replace=TRUE)
)

df<-merge(df,lonlat, by="SiteID")

count_df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(Species)+2, ncol = 0))
count_df$Species<-c(Species,"days","n_cameras")


days<-c(10,15,20,30)
n_cameras<-c(2,3,4)
runs<-10
day_counter<-2


for(i in 1:runs){
  for(k in 1:length(n_cameras)) {
    for(j in 1:length(days)) {
      cam1<-sample_n(lonlat, 1)
      lonlat[,4]<-unlist(transpose(as.list(distm(cam1[,1:2], lonlat[,1:2], fun = distHaversine))))
      closest<-lonlat[order(lonlat[,4])[1:n_cameras[k]],]
      subsample<-df[which(interaction(df$SiteID) %in% interaction(closest$SiteID)),]
      dates<-unique(subsample$Date)
      a<-sample(dates,1)
      b<-a+days[j]
      sample <- subsample[which(subsample$Date>=a & subsample$Date<b),]
      summary <- sample %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        summarise(count=length(Count>1))
      combined<-count_df %>%
        left_join(summary, by = "Species") %>%
        mutate(count = coalesce(count, 0))
      combined$count[length(Species)+1]<-days[j]
      combined$count[length(Species)+2]<-n_cameras[k]
      count_df[,day_counter]<-combined$count
      day_counter<-day_counter+1
    }
  }
}
```

It works and gives exactly what I would expect, it just takes a long time and I would like a more efficient way of running it. I do this kind of thing a lot so it would save a lot of time if I learnt to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code and was able to substitute the for loop with apply functions.

Some notes on your code:

1. your final output is not in a tidy format, so I also changed that;
2. don't use "summary" or "sample" as object names, because there are base R functions with the same name;
3. Add comments to explain the steps of your code (it took me a while to be able to understand);

My strategy was to make a function for the sampling of a single run (single_run), then I did a second function to run the single_run function any number of times.

Finally, I used another apply function to run over any number of combinations. This strategy avoids any loops and results in a tidy format data.frame.

```
# Your initial settings
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)
library(terra)

Sites<-c("Site1","Site2","Site3","Site4","Site5","Site6")
Dates<-seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-15"), by="days")
Species<-c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3")

lonlat<-data.frame(
  lon = c(15.0, 25.0, 12.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0),
  lat = c(22.0, 18.0, 25.0, 20.0, 18.0, 25.0),
  SiteID=Sites
)


df<-data.frame(
  SiteID=sample(Sites,20, replace=TRUE),
  Date=sample(Dates,20, replace=TRUE),
  Species=sample(Species,20, replace=TRUE),
  Count=sample(0:3,20, replace=TRUE)
)

df<-merge(df,lonlat, by="SiteID")

count_df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(Species)+2, ncol = 0))
count_df$Species<-c(Species,"days","n_cameras")


days<-c(10,15,20,30)
n_cameras<-c(2,3,4)
runs<-10
day_counter<-2

## My solution below
# function for a single run
single_run <- function(n_days,
                       n_cameras,
                       run){
  # get random coordinate for each camera
  cam1 <- sample_n(lonlat, 1)

  # Add a column with closest distance
  lonlat <- lonlat %>%
    mutate(closestDistance = distHaversine(cam1[,1:2], lonlat[,1:2]))

  # Store closest distance
  closest <- lonlat %>%
    arrange(closestDistance) %>%
    head(n_cameras) # number of cameras argument

  # Get the values from the original data frame selected previously
  df_subsample <- df %>%
    filter(SiteID %in% closest$SiteID)

  # First day for current run
  day_1 <- df_subsample %>%
    sample_n(1) %>% # samples one random row
    pull(Date) # gives tou the Date column values

  # the next day is after the previous plus the number of days argument
  day_next <- day_1 + n_days

  summary_sp <- df_subsample %>%
    filter(Date >= day_1, Date < day_next) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(count = length(Count>1)) %>%
    mutate(days = n_days, n_cameras = n_cameras) %>%
    mutate(day_counter = run)
  #
  return(summary_sp)
}

# example for a single run
single_run(n_days = 10,
           n_cameras = 20,
           run = 2)

# Put the combinations you want in a data frame
combinations <-
  cbind(days, n_cameras)

# make a function to apply a combination for any number of runs
apply_runs <- function(runs, day_camera_combination){
  lapply(1:runs, function(x){
    single_run(n_days = combinations[day_camera_combination , 1],
               n_cameras = combinations[day_camera_combination , 2],
               run = x)
  }) %>%
    bind_rows() # this line will bind all elements of the lapply result
}

# apply all runs through all combinations
bootsrap_result <- lapply(1:dim(combinations)[1],
                          function(x){
                            apply_runs(runs = 10, day_camera_combination = x)
                            })  %>%
  bind_rows()

head(bootsrap_result)
```